# Policy vs polymorphic speed

Tags: c++, oop

I read that using a policy class for a function that will be called in a tight loop is much faster than using a polymorphic function. However, I setup this demo and the timing indicates that it is exactly the opposite!? The policy version takes between 2-3x longer than the polymorphic version.

```
#include <iostream>

#include <boost/timer.hpp>

// Policy version
template < typename operation_policy>
class DoOperationPolicy : public operation_policy
{
  using operation_policy::Operation;

public:
  void Run(const float a, const float b)
  {
    Operation(a,b);
  }
};

class OperationPolicy_Add
{
protected:
  float Operation(const float a, const float b)
  {
    return a + b;
  }
};

// Polymorphic version
class DoOperation
{
public:
  virtual float Run(const float a, const float b)= 0;
};

class OperationAdd : public DoOperation
{
public:
  float Run(const float a, const float b)
  {
    return a + b;
  }
};

int main()
{
  boost::timer timer;

  unsigned int numberOfIterations = 1e7;

  DoOperationPolicy<OperationPolicy_Add> policy_operation;
  for(unsigned int i = 0; i < numberOfIterations; ++i)
    {
    policy_operation.Run(1,2);
    }
  std::cout << timer.elapsed() << " seconds." << std::endl;
  timer.restart();

  DoOperation* polymorphic_operation = new OperationAdd;
  for(unsigned int i = 0; i < numberOfIterations; ++i)
    {
    polymorphic_operation->Run(1,2);
    }
  std::cout << timer.elapsed() << " seconds." << std::endl;

}
```

Is there something wrong with the demo? Or is just incorrect that the policy should be faster?

Comment: It depends on your optimisation settings. Show us how your compiler is being invoked, and tell us what compiler it is.

Comment: Visual C++ 2010 optimizes the policy_operation loop away, your benchmark is off...

Comment: g++ optimizes away the policy loop as well.

Comment: It depends on your compiler (and optimization level). In debug mode it's likely to be slower, since the methodcalls probably won't be inlined (of course who cares about speed in debug?). It's also quite possible that there is no difference in performance, when making an optimized build (the compiler will inline the policy based approach, and might devirtualize and then inline the polymorphic approach since it knows the actual class of polymorphic_operation). Generally such microbenchmarks are problematic for making actual statements about performance.

Comment: the way you used it, it is a mixin

Comment: The `new` is unnecessary for polymorphism.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your benchmark is meaningless (sorry).

Making real benchmarks is hard, unfortunately, as compilers are very clever.

Things to look for here:

- devirtualization: the polymorphic call is expected to be slower because it is supposed to be virtual, but here the compiler can realize than `polymorphic_operation` is necessarily a `OperationAdd` and thus directly call `OperationAdd::Run` without invoking runtime dispatch
- inlining: since the compiler has access to the methods body, it can inline them, and avoid the function calls altogether.
- "dead store removal": values that are not used need not be stored, and the computations that lead to them and do not provoke side-effects can be avoided entirely.

Indeed, your entire benchmark code can be optimized to:

```
int main()
{
  boost::timer timer;

  std::cout << timer.elapsed() << " seconds." << std::endl;

  timer.restart();

  DoOperation* polymorphic_operation = new OperationAdd;

  std::cout << timer.elapsed() << " seconds." << std::endl;
}
```

Which is when you realize that you are not timing what you'd like to...

In order to make your benchmark meaningful you need to:

- prevent devirtualization
- force side-effects

To prevent devirtualization, just declare a `DoOperation& Get()` function, and then in another cpp file: `DoOperation& Get() { static OperationAdd O; return O; }`.

To force side-effects (only necessary if the methods are inlined): return the value and accumulate it, then display it.

---

In action using this program:

```
// test2.cpp
namespace so8746025 {

  class DoOperation
  {
  public:
    virtual float Run(const float a, const float b) = 0;
  };

  class OperationAdd : public DoOperation
  {
  public:
    float Run(const float a, const float b)
    {
      return a + b;
    }
  };

  class OperationAddOutOfLine: public DoOperation
  {
  public:
    float Run(const float a, const float b);
  };

  float OperationAddOutOfLine::Run(const float a, const float b)
  {
    return a + b;
  }

  DoOperation& GetInline() {
    static OperationAdd O;
    return O;
  }

  DoOperation& GetOutOfLine() {
    static OperationAddOutOfLine O;
    return O;
  }

} // namespace so8746025

// test.cpp
#include <iostream>

#include <boost/timer.hpp>

namespace so8746025 {

  // Policy version
  template < typename operation_policy>
  struct DoOperationPolicy
  {
    float Run(const float a, const float b)
    {
      return operation_policy::Operation(a,b);
    }
  };

  struct OperationPolicy_Add
  {
    static float Operation(const float a, const float b)
    {
      return a + b;
    }
  };

  // Polymorphic version
  class DoOperation
  {
  public:
    virtual float Run(const float a, const float b) = 0;
  };

  class OperationAdd : public DoOperation
  {
  public:
    float Run(const float a, const float b)
    {
      return a + b;
    }
  };

  class OperationAddOutOfLine: public DoOperation
  {
  public:
    float Run(const float a, const float b);
  };


  DoOperation& GetInline();
  DoOperation& GetOutOfLine();

} // namespace so8746025

using namespace so8746025;

int main()
{
  unsigned int numberOfIterations = 1e8;

  DoOperationPolicy<OperationPolicy_Add> policy;

  OperationAdd stackInline;
  DoOperation& virtualInline = GetInline();

  OperationAddOutOfLine stackOutOfLine;
  DoOperation& virtualOutOfLine = GetOutOfLine();


  boost::timer timer;

  float result = 0;

  for(unsigned int i = 0; i < numberOfIterations; ++i)  {
    result += policy.Run(1,2);
  }
  std::cout << "Policy: " << timer.elapsed() << " seconds (" << result << ")" << std::endl;


  timer.restart();
  result = 0;
  for(unsigned int i = 0; i < numberOfIterations; ++i)
  {
    result += stackInline.Run(1,2);
  }
  std::cout << "Stack Inline: " << timer.elapsed() << " seconds (" << result << ")" << std::endl;

  timer.restart();
  result = 0;
  for(unsigned int i = 0; i < numberOfIterations; ++i)
  {
    result += virtualInline.Run(1,2);
  }
  std::cout << "Virtual Inline: " << timer.elapsed() << " seconds (" << result << ")" << std::endl;

  timer.restart();
  result = 0;
  for(unsigned int i = 0; i < numberOfIterations; ++i)
  {
    result += stackOutOfLine.Run(1,2);
  }
  std::cout << "Stack Out Of Line: " << timer.elapsed() << " seconds (" << result << ")" << std::endl;

  timer.restart();
  result = 0;
  for(unsigned int i = 0; i < numberOfIterations; ++i)
  {
    result += virtualOutOfLine.Run(1,2);
  }
  std::cout << "Virtual Out Of Line: " << timer.elapsed() << " seconds (" << result << ")" << std::endl;

}
```

We get:

```
$ gcc --version
gcc (GCC) 4.3.2

$ ./testR
Policy: 0.17 seconds (6.71089e+07)
Stack Inline: 0.17 seconds (6.71089e+07)
Virtual Inline: 0.52 seconds (6.71089e+07)
Stack Out Of Line: 0.6 seconds (6.71089e+07)
Virtual Out Of Line: 0.59 seconds (6.71089e+07)
```

Note the subtle difference between devirtualization + inline and the absence of devirtualization.

Comment: And just as a note: be tight about what you time, here you have a memory allocation counting against `OperationAdd` (yes, supposed to be small wrt the loop but still...)

Answer (score 3):

FWIW I made it

- a policy, as opposed to mixn
- return the value
- use a volatile to avoid optimizing away of the loop **and** unrelated optimization of the loop (like, reducing load/stores due to loop unrolling and vectorization on targets that support it).
- compare with a direct, static function call
- use way more iterations
- compile with -O3 on gcc

Timings are:

```
DoDirect: 3.4 seconds.
Policy: 3.41 seconds.
Polymorphic: 3.4 seconds.
```

Ergo: there is no difference. Mainly because GCC is able to statically analyze the type of DoOperation* to be DoOperationAdd - there is vtable lookup inside the loop :)

#### IMPORTANT

If you wanted to benchmark *reallife* performance of this exact loop, instead of function invocation overhead, drop the volatile. The timings now become

```
DoDirect: 6.71089e+07 in 1.12 seconds.
Policy: 6.71089e+07 in 1.15 seconds.
Polymorphic: 6.71089e+07 in 3.38 seconds.
```

As you can see, without volatile, the compiler is able to optimize some load-store cycles away; I assume it might be doing loop unrolling+register allocation there (however I haven't inspected the machine code). The point is, that the *loop as a whole* can be optimized much more with the 'policy' approach than with the dynamic dispatch (i.e. the virtual method)

#### CODE

```
#include <iostream>

#include <boost/timer.hpp>

// Direct version
struct DoDirect {
    static float Run(const float a, const float b) { return a + b; }
};

// Policy version
template <typename operation_policy>
struct DoOperationPolicy {
    float Run(const float a, const float b) const {
        return operation_policy::Operation(a,b);
    }
};

struct OperationPolicy_Add {
    static float Operation(const float a, const float b) {
        return a + b;
    }
};

// Polymorphic version
struct DoOperation {
    virtual float Run(const float a, const float b) const = 0;
};

struct OperationAdd  : public DoOperation { 
    float Run(const float a, const float b) const { return a + b; } 
};

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    boost::timer timer;

    const unsigned long numberOfIterations = 1<<30ul;

    volatile float result = 0;
    for(unsigned long i = 0; i < numberOfIterations; ++i) {
        result += DoDirect::Run(1,2);
    }
    std::cout << "DoDirect: " << result << " in " << timer.elapsed() << " seconds." << std::endl;
    timer.restart();

    DoOperationPolicy<OperationPolicy_Add> policy_operation;
    for(unsigned long i = 0; i < numberOfIterations; ++i) {
        result += policy_operation.Run(1,2);
    }
    std::cout << "Policy: " << result << " in " << timer.elapsed() << " seconds." << std::endl;
    timer.restart();

    result = 0;
    DoOperation* polymorphic_operation = new OperationAdd;
    for(unsigned long i = 0; i < numberOfIterations; ++i) {
        result += polymorphic_operation->Run(1,2);
    }
    std::cout << "Polymorphic: " << result << " in " << timer.elapsed() << " seconds." << std::endl;

}
```

Comment: Have adapted my answer to point out the difference between benchmarking invocation overhead, and benchmarking _whole-loop-optimization_

Comment: What is the difference between a policy and a mixin?

Comment: Where did you add volatile? Also, can you expand on "invocation overhead" vs "whole-loop-optimization" - How did you prevent the loop unrolling?

Comment: @DavidDoria: sorry I updated the code after doing the test without volatile. Sorry about that. Fixed

Comment: @DavidDoria: A policy is a class that you delegate to for the definition of a certain part of the behaviour of the templated class. A mixin is when the generic class _inherits_ from the template argument (inheritance models `is-a` semantics - the Liskov Substitution Principle of OO; injecting a class into the base-class hierarchy makes a classes' 'identity' partially defined by the mix-in).

Answer (score 2):

Turn on optimisation. The policy-based variant profits highly from that because most intermediate steps are completely optimised out, while the polymorphic version cannot skip for example the dereferencing of the object.

Comment: The compiler might be able to optimize the polymorphic version just as well as the policy-based (it's unlikely , but still). Since it can see the initialization of `polymorphic_operation` it knows the actual type referenced by the pointer, so it could devirtualize the call to `Run` to a nonvirtual function call, afterwards it can inline that function and then see that `this` is never used inside the function body, so it could remove the dereferencing of the object as dead code. Of course this depends on knowing the actual type (and the compiler being smarter then is likely, but still)

Comment: g++ doesn't do this. Is it even allowed to?

Comment: @filmor: it is. It conforms to the "as if" rule. Clang can perform a number of devirtualizations so I guess modern versions of g++ can too.

Comment: I can't cite any reference, but I don't see any reason why it shouldn't be, since all information are available at compiletime. It does do those transformation, if `polymorphic_operation` is declared as `OperationAdd polymorphic_operation` (so the actual type is really clear). Since it can see the call to the constructor it could recognize that case too (if it's smart enough of course).

Answer (score 2):

You have to turn on optimization, and make sure that

- both code parts actually do the same thing (which they currently do not, your policy-variant does not return the result)
- the result is used for something, so that the compiler does not discard the code path altogether (just sum the results and print them somewhere should be enough)

Answer (score 1):

I had to change your policy code to return the computed value:

```
float Run(const float a, const float b)
{
  return Operation(a,b);
}
```

Secondly, I had to store the returned value to ensure that the loop wouldn't be optimized away:

```
int main()
{
  unsigned int numberOfIterations = 1e9;
  float answer = 0.0;

  boost::timer timer;
  DoOperationPolicy<OperationPolicy_Add> policy_operation;
  for(unsigned int i = 0; i < numberOfIterations; ++i)
  {
    answer += policy_operation.Run(1,2);
  }
  std::cout << "Policy got " << answer << " in " << timer.elapsed() << " seconds" << std::endl;

  answer = 0.0;
  timer.restart();
  DoOperation* polymorphic_operation = new OperationAdd;
  for(unsigned int i = 0; i < numberOfIterations; ++i)
  {
    answer += polymorphic_operation->Run(1,2);
  }
  std::cout << "Polymo got " << answer << " in " << timer.elapsed() << " seconds" << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Without optimizations on g++ 4.1.2:

```
Policy got 6.71089e+07 in 13.75 seconds
Polymo got 6.71089e+07 in 7.52 seconds
```

With `-O3` on g++ 4.1.2:

```
Policy got 6.71089e+07 in 1.18 seconds
Polymo got 6.71089e+07 in 3.23 seconds
```

So the policy is definitely faster once optimizations are turned on.

Comment: the benchmark isn't accurate due to small number of iterations

Comment: Sounds strange... do you get the same result with `OperationAdd oa; DoOperation& polymorphic_operation = oa;` (gcc should be able to devirtualize that call: which versions are you using ?)

Comment: @sehe The benchmark is most certainly accurate. But to allay your concerns, I've increased the number of iterations. It got the same result.

Comment: @chrisaycock: I second Matthieu's motion then. See my own answer that speaks differently

Comment: Found the difference. If you make the return value volatile, you can see the difference disappear. Apparently, without it, the whole body gets inlined and I presume there is some loop unrolling going on (need to check assembly output?)

Comment: @MatthieuM. I get the same result with both references and pointers. My (old) version of g++ doesn't appear to be doing any vtable optimizations.

Comment: Have adapted my answer to point out the difference between benchmarking invocation overhead, and benchmarking _whole-loop-optimization_

Comment: @sehe I get the same results for `volatile` return types too.